# Matlab overwrite random columns in matrix with zeros?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm using the code below to replace random-looking columns in a matrix with zeros (in reality they're not random, but correspond to degrees of freedom of human movement).  The code works, but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this.  The matrix has 128 columns and I'm not done yet!

```
subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal = subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Q;
for column = 1:9
    switch column
        case 2
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
        case 3
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
        case 5
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
        case 6
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
        case 8
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
        case 9
            subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,column) = zeros(m,1);
   end
end
```

Comment: I think the above code can be replaced with `subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,[2 3 5 6 8 9]) = 0`. Maybe mess with that until you get what you want. How are you generating the `case` numbers, i.e. how are you getting 2,3,5,6,8,9?

Comment: That works! Can't believe it was that simple. I have to generate the case numbers manually, but this will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jucestain suggested you don't need to update the columns 1 by one. Matlab allows you to enter a vector as indexing argument, so suppose you have:

```
idx = [2,3,5,6,8,9];
```

You can directly assign zero to all columns:

```
subject(subNum).trial(trialNum).Qsagittal(:,idx) = 0;
```

Just a guess, but it seems like you want each second and third number to be in `idx`. You can achieve this easily like so:

```
idx = 1:9; 
idx(1:3:9) = [];
```

For future reference, if someone actually wants to assign 6 out of 9 random columns to zero, it can be achieved by using this index:

```
idx = randperm(9,6)
```